# How to save large set of rows and columns from .xlsx output in a file

Tags: python, pandas

I  have a `.xlsx` file with large set of rows and columns, and I would like to save the desired output in .csv or .txt file.

```
import pandas as pd
 
def foo():
    data = pd.read_excel('file/path/filename.xlsx')
    print(data)

    f = open('Output.txt', 'w')
    print(data.head(50),file = f)
    f.close()
```

I get the `Output.txt` as

```
Col1 Col2 ... Col99
1     1   ... 2
2     4   ... 3
.     .   ... .  
.     .   ... . 
4     2   ... 3
```

instead of all the rows and columns. I realize that I'm just saving whats been printed on screen, can anyone suggest how to save such columns and rows completely in a .csv or .txt?

Answer (score 3):

```
data.to_csv('path_to_csv')
```

Did you try this already?

```
import pandas as pd
 
def foo():
    data = pd.read_excel('file/path/filename.xlsx')
    data.to_csv('path_to_csv', index=False)
```

Comment: yes, but if I also want to save `print(data[col1].values)`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) (*which by default prints every piece of your DataFrame as it is*):

```
def foo():
    data = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
    # print(data)

    with open('Output.txt', 'w') as f:
        data.head(50).to_string(f, index=False)
```